# DNS error named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, named-conf

I am using Centos Web Panel, everything was just working like it normally should... However the Bind DNS just stopped working out of nowhere.

Here is the error code provided:

```
● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-04-10 00:02:41 UTC; 4min 41s ago
  Process: 4363 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 10 00:02:41 server.odhosting.org bash[4363]: zone themerchandiseman.com/IN: loaded serial 2013071600
Apr 10 00:02:41 server.odhosting.org bash[4363]: zone bdfinancegroup.com/IN: loaded serial 2013071600
Apr 10 00:02:41 server.odhosting.org bash[4363]: zone saltymanufacturing.com/IN: loaded serial 2013071600
Apr 10 00:02:41 server.odhosting.org bash[4363]: zone cryptonewstv.com/IN: loaded serial 2013071600
Apr 10 00:02:41 server.odhosting.org bash[4363]: zone odmarketing.org/IN: loaded serial 2013071600
Apr 10 00:02:41 server.odhosting.org bash[4363]: zone talkthatheals.com/IN: loaded serial 2013071600
Apr 10 00:02:41 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 10 00:02:41 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Apr 10 00:02:41 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state.
Apr 10 00:02:41 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: named.service failed.
```

From what I can gather, everything is loading properly but then just fails.

I have glue records properly set, name servers are also done properly. (this happened recently wen trying to configure DKIM, dmarc, SPF records to the DNS template. Deleted the template, re-built DNS zones. However still not able to start the BIND DNS.

If anyone has seen this before and knows what might be wrong / has fixed this before please reply.

Also more information regarding the error with the "journalctl -xe" command and the following was the output:

```
********************************************
 Welcome to CWP (CentOS WebPanel) server
********************************************

CWP Wiki: http://wiki.centos-webpanel.com
CWP Forum: http://forum.centos-webpanel.com
CWP Support: http://centos-webpanel.com/support-services

 00:19:42 up 22 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    cpe-108-184-219- 00:19    0.00s  0.05s  0.00s sh /root/.bash_

[root@server ~]# journalctl -xe
Apr 10 00:19:43 server.odhosting.org postfix/qmgr[1459]: AF56BC152F2: removed
Apr 10 00:20:01 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: Started Session 8 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-8.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-8.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Apr 10 00:20:01 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: Starting Session 8 of user root
-- Subject: Unit session-8.scope has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-8.scope has begun starting up.
Apr 10 00:20:01 server.odhosting.org CROND[8019]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org postfix/pickup[1458]: A0479C152F1: uid=0 fr
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org postfix/cleanup[7961]: A0479C152F1: message
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org opendkim[1022]: A0479C152F1: no signing tab
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org opendkim[1022]: A0479C152F1: no signature d
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org postfix/qmgr[1459]: A0479C152F1: from=<root
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org postfix/local[7968]: A0479C152F1: to=<root@
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org postfix/qmgr[1459]: A0479C152F1: removed

[root@server ~]# journalctl -xe
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
--
-- A new session with the ID 7 has been created for the user root.
--
-- The leading process of the session is 7887.
Apr 10 00:19:41 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: Started Session 7 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-7.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-7.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Apr 10 00:19:41 server.odhosting.org sshd[7887]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 10 00:19:41 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: Starting Session 7 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-7.scope has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-7.scope has begun starting up.
Apr 10 00:19:43 server.odhosting.org postfix/pickup[1458]: AF56BC152F2: uid=0 from=<root>
Apr 10 00:19:43 server.odhosting.org postfix/cleanup[7961]: AF56BC152F2: message-id=<20180410001943.AF56BC152F2@server.odhosting.org>
Apr 10 00:19:43 server.odhosting.org opendkim[1022]: AF56BC152F2: no signing table match for 'root@server.odhosting.org'
Apr 10 00:19:43 server.odhosting.org opendkim[1022]: AF56BC152F2: no signature data
Apr 10 00:19:43 server.odhosting.org postfix/qmgr[1459]: AF56BC152F2: from=<root@server.odhosting.org>, size=639, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 10 00:19:43 server.odhosting.org postfix/local[7968]: AF56BC152F2: to=<root@server.odhosting.org>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.04/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent
Apr 10 00:19:43 server.odhosting.org postfix/qmgr[1459]: AF56BC152F2: removed
Apr 10 00:20:01 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: Started Session 8 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-8.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-8.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Apr 10 00:20:01 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: Starting Session 8 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-8.scope has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-8.scope has begun starting up.
Apr 10 00:20:01 server.odhosting.org CROND[8019]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org postfix/pickup[1458]: A0479C152F1: uid=0 from=<root>
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org postfix/cleanup[7961]: A0479C152F1: message-id=<20180410002003.A0479C152F1@server.odhosting.org>
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org opendkim[1022]: A0479C152F1: no signing table match for 'root@server.odhosting.org'
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org opendkim[1022]: A0479C152F1: no signature data
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org postfix/qmgr[1459]: A0479C152F1: from=<root@server.odhosting.org>, size=3811, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org postfix/local[7968]: A0479C152F1: to=<root@server.odhosting.org>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.04/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent
Apr 10 00:20:03 server.odhosting.org postfix/qmgr[1459]: A0479C152F1: removed
```

To be clear BIND DNS was working and configured properly, something has been changed, however I do not know what it was. (The error happened after restarting the DNS)

Things I have already tried:

1. Rebuild DNS
2. Remove all DKIM & SPF settings
3. Double Check IP Address for NS
4. Ensure that all domains use the listed NS
5. Reboot Sever
6. Remove & Add Zone Files
7. Double Check Glue Records & Verified

I managed to find more information / errors:

```
● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-04-10 01:04:08 UTC; 10s ago
  Process: 15631 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named -c ${NAMEDCONF} $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 15622 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 10 01:04:08 server.odhosting.org named[15633]: sizing zone task pool based on 17 zones
Apr 10 01:04:08 server.odhosting.org named[15633]: dns_master_load: named.ca:10: isc_lex_gettoken() failed: unbalanced parentheses
Apr 10 01:04:08 server.odhosting.org named[15633]: dns_master_load: named.ca:10: unbalanced parentheses
Apr 10 01:04:08 server.odhosting.org named[15633]: could not configure root hints from 'named.ca': unbalanced parentheses
Apr 10 01:04:08 server.odhosting.org named[15633]: loading configuration: unbalanced parentheses
Apr 10 01:04:08 server.odhosting.org named[15633]: exiting (due to fatal error)
Apr 10 01:04:08 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 10 01:04:08 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Apr 10 01:04:08 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state.
Apr 10 01:04:08 server.odhosting.org systemd[1]: named.service failed.
```

Especially this line of code if anyone know how to fix:

```
could not configure root hints from 'named.ca': unbalanced parentheses
```

Comment: The error was within the 'named.ca' file where there was an additional ")" I do not know how it got there but that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The original code was the following within the named.ca file:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-38.el7_3.2 <<>> +bufsize=1200 +norec @a.root-servers.net
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;;      Got      answer:                        
                     ;
                     ;

                     ;
                     ;EDNS: version: 0, flags:
      )


;.      0      IN      NS      
;;      ANSWER      SECTION:            
.      518400      IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
;;      ADDITIONAL      SECTION:            
a.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      198.41.0.4
a.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:503:ba3e::2:30
b.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.228.79.201
b.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:84::b
c.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.33.4.12
c.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:2::c
d.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      199.7.91.13
d.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:2d::d
e.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.203.230.10
e.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:a8::e
f.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.5.5.241
f.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:2f::f
g.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.112.36.4
g.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:12::d0d
h.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      198.97.190.53
h.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:1::53
i.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.36.148.17
i.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:7fe::53
j.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.58.128.30
j.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:503:c27::2:30
k.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      193.0.14.129
k.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:7fd::1
l.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      199.7.83.42
l.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:9f::42
m.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      202.12.27.33
m.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:dc3::35
;;      Query      time:            msec
;;      SERVER:      198.41.0.4#53(198.41.0.4)            
;;      WHEN:      Po            22      10:14:44      CEST2017
;;      MSG      SIZE            811
```

Where as the correct or proper 'named.ca' file should be the following, minus a stray ")"

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-38.el7_3.2 <<>> +bufsize=1200 +norec @a.root-servers.net
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;;      Got      answer:                        
                     ;
                     ;

                     ;
                     ;EDNS: version: 0, flags:



;.      0      IN      NS      
;;      ANSWER      SECTION:            
.      518400      IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.      518400      IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
;;      ADDITIONAL      SECTION:            
a.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      198.41.0.4
a.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:503:ba3e::2:30
b.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.228.79.201
b.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:84::b
c.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.33.4.12
c.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:2::c
d.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      199.7.91.13
d.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:2d::d
e.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.203.230.10
e.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:a8::e
f.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.5.5.241
f.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:2f::f
g.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.112.36.4
g.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:12::d0d
h.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      198.97.190.53
h.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:1::53
i.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.36.148.17
i.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:7fe::53
j.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      192.58.128.30
j.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:503:c27::2:30
k.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      193.0.14.129
k.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:7fd::1
l.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      199.7.83.42
l.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:500:9f::42
m.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      A      202.12.27.33
m.root-servers.net.      3600000      IN      AAAA      2001:dc3::35
;;      Query      time:            msec
;;      SERVER:      198.41.0.4#53(198.41.0.4)            
;;      WHEN:      Po            22      10:14:44      CEST2017
;;      MSG      SIZE            811
```

I find it slightly funny how one nearly always finds answers right after asking a community for help. Nevertheless, I hope this can solve someone elses problem in the near future or even help me figure this out again if needed. Cheers everyone, it appeared to be 100% the servers fault =P